# " Ни одна киноактриса так хороша на театральной сцене, и ни одна театральная актриса так хороша в кино, как Вивьен Ли". Как исправить этот текст?

Tags: семантика

В этом тексте явно есть какая-то ошибка. Что в нём надо исправить, чтобы довести его до ума?

*"Ни одна киноактриса так хороша на театральной сцене, и ни одна театральная актриса так хороша в кино, как Вивьен Ли".*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Ни одна киноактриса **не была** так хороша на театральной сцене и ни одна театральная актриса **не была** так хороша в кино, как Вивьен Ли.*

Здесь был пропущен глагол с отрицанием.

Запятую не ставим, так как есть общее сравнение.